# What's Clair's reasoning for wanting to get rid of Christina Gallagher?

Tags: house-of-cards

In season 2 of *House of Cards* Clair makes efforts to get rid of Christina Gallagher. She mentions in the meeting with the first lady that she has "a problem when someone sleeps with their boss". She then tells Christina to speak to the first lady.

Anyway, what's her reasoning behind this? What does Clair stand to gain?